# Angular has build --prod, How about Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I want to upload my Laravel project via FTP but I don't want to upload such numerous amount of files.

As seen on Angular `ng build --prod`, you can easily build the project and compress it, and it's working on the FTP server.

How do you do the similar things in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create [PHARs](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) (which is somewhat similar to Java's Jar). However, take note that using PHARs is not as straightforward as using individual PHP files. And it may depend on your project structure. Also, according to Taylor Otwell, [it's not something he planned to support](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3502).

One of the tools you an use to create PHARs is [PHP Box](https://github.com/box-project/box2).